# How to render video and audio

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to implement my own media player. What is the best way to render video and audio? At this point I am thinking to use  SurfaceView and AudioTrack classes, but not sure if it is the best option. I am interested in SDK and NDK solutions.

File output on regular desktop is non-blocking, that is OS takes care of buffering and  actual disk writes are asynchronous to the thread that initiates the output. Does the same principle apply to video and audio output? If not, I would need to run a separate thread to handle output asynchronously from decoding/demuxing.

What free software decoders are available for android? I am thinking to use ffmpeg. Can relatively recent (say, top 30% in terms of CPU power) tablet  handle 1,280×720 and 1,920×1,080 formats in software mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rock Player is an open source player for android [(it's official site)](http://www.rockplayer.com/index_en.html). You can get the source from [it's source code download page](http://www.rockplayer.com/tech_en.html). They use the [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) which is a LGPL library. Pock Player developers do extra efforts to write some asm making decoding faster.